# How to define the constants the used also by the subclass?

Tags: c#, .net, constants

I need to define some constants that will be used by the base class and its sub class. 
Not sure what is the correct way to define them.

I understand the differences of const, readonly, static const, as well as public, protected, and private (while I seldom see "protected" is used in C#). How these constant should be defined? should them be public const, or public readonly, or private constant, or private readonly and use public getter/setter for subclass to use, or should them be defined as protected?

Another question is about the variable FilePath in the BaseClass. FilePath will be used by some functions in the BaseClass as placeholder (the real value will be provided by subclass), should I define it as virtual?

Could somebody provide general rules to follow? The following is an example of what I have:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public const string Country = "USA";
    public const string State = "California";
    public const string City = "San Francisco";

    public virtual string FilePath
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
         set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

public class Class1 : BaseClass {

     public Class1() {
         FilPath = "C:\test";
     }

     public string GetAddress() {
       return City + ", " + State + ", " + Country; 
     }

     public void CreateFile() {
       if (!Directory.Exist(FilePath)) {
            //create folder, etc 
        }
     }         
}
```

Comment: Why not declare the constants in the subclass that actually uses them, instead of the base class that does not?

Comment: You might also be able to use `public const string Address = City + ", " + State + ", " + Country;`

Comment: @Chris Those constants will be used by more than one subclasses. I do not want to define them multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

If you can define the constants as `const` then do so. If that is not possible, go with `static readonly`.

If the constants are to be used outside of the class then they need to be `internal` or `public`. If only the base class and its descendants are going to use them then make them `protected`.

If `FilePath` *can* be provided by subclasses, then it has to be `virtual`. If it *must* be provided by subclasses, it should be `abstract`.

Comment: "If the constants are to be used outside of the class then they need to be internal or public". This confuses me. should it be defined as private property and use getter by subclass?

Comment: @ericyoung: How did `private` come into this discussion? The visibility should be the most restrictive that still lets you do what you need. Since you need `Class1` to have access it cannot be `private`, so the minimum is `protected`. If there are also other classes that need to access these constants then you move up to `internal` and `public`.

Comment: I really don't want const fields/properties to be public. I thought private will be better to let subclass use getter/setter. Or even define them as protected. But I seldom saw people use protected. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I would make BaseClass an abstract class (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(v=vs.71).aspx).  As for const vs. static readonly, its mainly a matter of taste.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    // ... constant definitions

    // Members that must be implemented by subclasses
    public abstract string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```